# WebStorm vs Brackets href linking

Tags: html, css, webstorm

So I've only just noticed this since I've been playing around with different Editors to get a feel for the differences and since I'm working on front-end, I was recommended to try WebStorm (11) by some friends.

I created a project in Brackets initially and opened it up in WebStorm to work in. All my links to files such as `CSS` and `Images` were broken in WebStorm.

I want to know why Brackets does their linking differently to WebStorm as I'm confused as to what the right convention is and why Brackets would even allow differences.

**Here is an example:**

---

**In Brackets:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='/css/main.css'>
```

Notice the extra `/` before `css/main.css`

**OR**

```
background: url('/img/sprites.png')
```

---

**In  WebStorm:**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='css/main.css'>
```

this time without the `/`

**OR**

```
background: url('../img/sprites.png')
```

in webstorm it required `..`

---

Any clarification would be super helpful on this.

Comment: You'd be better off looking through the documentation but it looks like an output setting to me.

Comment: What does "broken" mean? How can a link be "broken" inside a *text editor*?! Clarify please.

Comment: @deceze by broken I mean it doesn't pull through the code for say the 'css' so you get a raw page instead

Comment: *...when launching the page using the web server built into the editor* that is, right? That just depends on what the editor has set as the document root, which is likely configurable somewhere in the settings.

Comment: okay but can i ask which way you guys write yours based on the examples above?

Comment: I'm still confused here -- what problem do you face exactly? Are you saying that WS does not insert leading `/` .. or it does not resolve such links (in editor) correctly? If so -- you need to mark parent folder of your `css` or `img` as `Resource Root` -- this way the `/css/...` will be treated relative to that parent folder.

Comment: Or maybe you are having issue with WebStorm's own built-in web server (which may require special kind of URLs/domain name to have such `/css/...` links to work nicely)? In such case --- why not use proper web server (Apache/nginx/IIS/etc)?